# How to join segments of a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have found different answers elsewhere that will work, but I can't quite figure out why my code is not working properly. What I am trying to do is take a list of alphabetical characters and join the first 4, second 4, third 4, etc. elements. I'll paste an example below to make this more clear.

If given the following list:
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'I', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

I want to combine the elements so that I receive the following output:

['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL', 'IMNO', 'QRST', 'UVWX', 'YZ']

I thought I identified a good solution on my own, but it doesn't seem to work. What I tried was:

```
x = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLIMNOQRSTUVWXYZ'
y = 4

def wrap(string, max_width):
    slist = [char for char in string]
    new = []
    for i in range(0, len(slist), max_width):
        new.append(''.join(slist[i:max_width]))
    return new

wrap(x, y)
```

The output that I get from this is:

```
['ABCD', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

I would appreciate if if someone could help me identify what is wrong and help me fix it. Like I said previously, I have found other answers online that will do what I want, but I really want to figure out where I went wrong here.

Comment: 1) `x` is not a valid string. 2) The indentation in your function is wrong. 3) You do not assign the returned function result to anything. 4) In general, you are on the right track. Be reminded that you can iterate over strings, just like over lists. [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#) can help you understand, why your program does not work. The slicing method is `[start:stop:step]`.

Comment: @Mr.T Regarding points 1 and 2, thank you! I copied and pasted and made some quick edits to make the question more readable, and I forgot to fix those issues after copying and pasting. I'll take a look at PythonTutor and see if I can figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: @Mr.T I took a look at PythonTutor. I haven't encountered this before. As you can likely tell, I am new to this. It was very helpful! Along with your [start:stop:step] tip, I was able to figure out where I went wrong. Peter Mason below summarized the conclusion I came to well. Thank you very much for your input!

Comment: Always a pleasure to help people who want to learn. Enjoy exploring Python and its amazing libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there was logic issues in the for loop:

You were trying to add items between i:max_width. However max_width is always 4 and when i is > 4 you get no items return as it is an empty string.
Instead I have added max_width to meaning the grouping is always the same size:

```
x = "ABCDEFGHIJKLIMNOQRSTUVWXYZ"
y = 4

def wrap(string, max_width):
    slist = [char for char in string]
    new = []
    for i in range(0,len(slist),max_width):
        new.append(''.join(slist[i:(i+max_width)]))
    return new

print(wrap(x, y))
```

Comment: Thank you! I just came to this conclusion with the help of Mr T as well. I definitely appreciate your answer though! It's those silly mistakes that still get me.

Answer (score 0):

Those earlier posts from @Peter Mason working fine as it just modified 'minimally' original code.  However, the original code can be improved further to save a few steps: (the slist = .... is redundant, as string is a character sequence and can be directly index-access)

```py
    >>> s = uppers = "ABCDEFGHIJKLIMNOQRSTUVWXYZ"
    >>> max_width = 4
    >>> newStr = []
    >>> for i in range(0, len(s), max_width):
        newStr.append(''.join(s[i:i+4]))
    
        
    >>> newStr
    ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL', 'IMNO', 'QRST', 'UVWX', 'YZ']
    >>> 

   Or, list comprehension:

         def wrap(string, max_width):
            return [''.join(string[i:i+max_width]) 
                            for i in range(0, len(string), max_width)]
        
        >>> wrap(s, 4)
        ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL', 'IMNO', 'QRST', 'UVWX', 'YZ']
        >>>
```